# 4 monitors, 2 identical GPUs and Linux

Tags: linux, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have two NVIDA GT610 cards on a ASUS X79 Sabertooth board and they are not SLI connected (they actually don't even support SLI).
I also have 4 monitors, 2 connected to each card.

Theoretically speaking, this should just work. But reality is another thing.

I just found that NVIDIA removed +3 monitors support in basic mosaic mode (bit***s!), so that leaves me with nouveau.

Is nouveau able to use 2 GPUs and 4 monitors at the same time? And all that, in the same X server (so I can freely drag windows from one monitor to another).

If not, what else can I do to use my 4 monitors?

Comment: Can you simply try nouveau?

Comment: Can be useful [this answer?](http://superuser.com/a/91590/257269)

Comment: @Ramhound I'm trying it right now, and only 2 monitors are working. Is there awy way I can tell nouveau to use the 4 of them?

Comment: @Hastur the answer you link is a really vague answer. It just says "you can you it with xrandr", but it's not saying anything about how to do it.

Comment: I didn't post because there was the full answer... If so I simply flagged your question as just answered there. :-) I only hope it could help... or at least it could give you a different path (that you didn't know) to solve your problem. [3 second after on google...](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Using_Multiple_Screens) In the hope this time it helps. :)

Comment: @Hastur the second link didn't help me either :(  It seems like 2 GPUs on Linux is something that no human has ever achieved, not in this universe at least.

Comment: [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XineramaHowTo) something more plain. That's probably my last google on it... for the moment :)

Comment: @Hastur Binary NVIDIA driver is not an option. As I already mentioned in my question, they removed support for +3 monitors in basic mosaic, and Xinerama is just a pain to use. Thank you anyways